# Backward compatibility for iOS build SDKs

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, osx-yosemite

I would like to run old application which has a support of iOS 5.0 and less. It has a **deployment target 5.0**. The thing is that:

I have upgraded system to Yosemite OS 10.10 and lowest Xcode version I have 5.0. Now when I look on base SDK and I see below picture.

[image]

As you see the least build SDK shown s  iOS 7.0. No other lower version is there.

I heard or I read some where that you can also use lower version SDK here. By copying SDKs to some where or any other means. I would like to know a better approach here.

**Edit:**

I have a requirement of one application which was developed in Xcode 4.6 for iOS 5.0. So that just to check that application flow I need to download Xcode 4.6. Is it so? Can we don't include older SDKs in newer version of Xcode?

Comment: Doesn't SDK 7.0 support iOS 5.0 and lower then?

Comment: Yes It is. But Some compatibility (like deprecation) is there. So I need base SDK as iOS 6.0. I know that Apple has declared that build should be made from iOS 7.0 but there is an odd requirement here.

Comment: Your best bet is to have an iOS 5 device for testing and a tool like [Deploymate](http://www.deploymateapp.com)

Comment: Apple has not declared that build should be made from iOS7 minimum, Apple has declared that build have to be made from iOS7. There are no reason to use previous SDK for an App available on AppStore.
If you have a particular reason, please explain it clearly so people can find a way to solve this.
But, for me, the only solution would be to download previous SDK and copy it into xcode SDK folder

Comment: Your question is confusing. You say you have an old app that supports iOS 5.0 and *earlier*. What do you want it to support now?

Comment: @rmaddy: As from my knowledge that Xcode 5.0 has base SDK iOS 7.0. Earlier version of Xcode like Xcode 4.6 and later were base SDK iOS 6.0. So that it is the only option that I have to download older Xcode just to test application working flow (Which was developed in Xcode 4.5 for iOS 5.0).

Comment: @Kampai You didn't answer my question. What versions of iOS do you wish to support now?

Comment: @rmaddy - I found one way. One of my friend told me that from Xcode.app package content path like `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk` gives sdk for iOS 7.1. So doing same for Xcode 4.6 and copy iOS 6.0 sdk to this path will do the trick. I never tried this. Is it safe to do this?

Comment: NO. You should always build for the latest SDK (iOS 8 right now). If something is deprecated, then building with an earlier SDK won't help you, because the method will still be deprecated on device... You should always use the latest SDK, and set the Base Deployment Target to the oldest OS you want to support. You can build your app for iOS 8 with a deployment target of iOS 5 and then test it on an iOS 5 device if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should not attempt to build your application with an old version of Xcode. The only version of Xcode supported on Yosemite is Xcode 6.1, which only ships with the iOS 8 SDK. You should build for the latest SDK, and set the Deployment Target to iOS 5 if you want your code to run there (by degrading gracefully using `NSClassFromString` and `respondsToSelector:` checks)

Comment: The application won't able to start, How I'm going to build it? BTW I just need to check application flow (works or not), not required to build it.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you have a binary which is already compiled, then you can use the latest version of Xcode to copy it to your device and test it, and there is no SDK involved. If you do not have a binary, then you need to build the application. The best way to do it is to use the latest version of Xcode and of the iOS SDK.

Comment: Yes that I know. Sir I do follow the same. What consequence here is I have a source code (very old) which is not meant for newer Xcode. (e.g. If you know when iOS 7 was launch, Xibs are not supported initially and layout was mis matched in Xcode 5). Similarly now I have issues like that - Need of Xcode 4.6, which I don't have. So my simple question is can any one know that Xcode provide mix both iOS 6 and 7 SDKs support for that.

Comment: No it can't. Xcode only supports the latest iOS SDK at the time of its release. If you copy an old SDK into a newer Xcode like you suggest, it might appear to work at first, but you'll eventually run into a lot of unpredictable issues.  Xcode 4.4.1 is still available for download from developer.apple.com, though. You might need an older OS X to run it...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Ya I think that's better to follow.